# Crash with MySQL connector c++ in CentOS; Related to library conflict?

Tags: c++, linux, mysql-connector

**EDIT :** I've since stopped using std::strings as arguments to these functions and the problems have gone away.  It seems to be a serious error related to string lifetime and scope.  I wish I understood what was going on a little better, but wanted to leave another breadcrumb for others who might be fighting with similar anomalies.**/Edit**

So I'm trying to write a database access routine using the MySQL C++ connector (built from source) and am getting an anomalous termination at the following code location:

```
//Change the active table and populate the member TableInfo object
void DatabaseInterface::ChangeTable(string tableName)
{
    string sqlString;
    int numFields;
    int numRecords;
    //Crash in this call
    connection->setSchema(tableName);
//More after this, but we never get here anyway...
```

After the program terminates, the message in the console is:

```
   warning: .dynamic section for "/lib/libnsl.so.1" is not at the expected address
    warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations
    [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
    [New Thread 0xb7fecb90 (LWP 23590)]
    [Thread 0xb7fecb90 (LWP 23590) exited]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/share/gdb/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 469, in to_string
        return self.val['_M_dataplus']['_M_p'].string (encoding, length = len)
    RuntimeError: Error reading string from inferior: Input/output error
```

That last RuntimeError seems like its indicating a nulled parameter being argued into the function, and stepping into the following code, I see that the address is not being allocated.  The debugger sees a value, but the memory location doesn't seem to exist.  In fact, attempting to view the location of the variable in the memory window results in an error.

```
bool ControlInterface::GenerateCmdSet()
{
    int nRecords;
    int nFields;
    string sqlString;

    string cardCmdTable;

    cardCmdTable = "card_command";

    dbInterface.ChangeTable(cardCmdTable);
```

Is it possible that I've got an issue with a library conflict, or a missing library?  I'm relatively new to linux, and finding it hard to appreciate while fighting with distros, flavors, dependencies, etc.

Comment: What happens when you call different members of the connection object, does that terminate the app as well? Also, have you checked the 'ldd' output of your binary to make sure it's using the correct library from the correct path?

Comment: @Luke: Other members of the connection object work, so long as they aren't declared with a string or char* as a parameter.  'connection' is an instance of sql::Connection and has been an issue from the start.  I've noticed that if I limit the context of a string parameter, it allows the calls to succeed.  It doesn't seem to help here.  I've 'new()'d' the string, which gives me a good memory location, but then doesn't properly accept the value that I want to place in it.  It's a curious situation.  As far as the Idd, I'm unsure of what that would entail.

Comment: Interesting. "ldd" just tells you which libraries your binary is using. So if your executable is called "dbapp", then you would just run "ldd dbapp" and verify it's using the correct libraries. This sounds like a linker issue, possibly mixing different C++ runtimes. It's hard to say without having access to the source, but I would look at how the library ('sql'?) is compiled, and verify it was built identical to the app that you are building. Are you using a release or debug build? If you are only trying one, have you tried the other?

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but it seems strange that you're passing a table name to a function `connection::setSchema()` that expects a schema name.